# Difference between LG-1 and FD-1 ring light accessories for Olympus TG-4

Tags: macro, point-and-shoot, olympus, accessories, ring-flash

I'm considering the Olympus TG-4 camera, because it could have a good combination of macro and ruggedness.  One of its macro features is that it has got native accessories for ring illumination.  There is a somewhat older [LG-1](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1042488-REG/olympus_v3271200w000_led_macro_ring_light.html)
[image]

and a newer [FD-1](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1243546-REG/olympus_v327130bw000_fd_1_flash_diffuser.html)
[image]
[image]

LG-1 looks like a light guide.  FD-1 looks like a reflector with a diffuser.  Is this a correct guess?  How different are they actually?  Have they got different pros and cons?

related: [Review of TG-4 with FD-1](http://cameras.olympus.com/tg4fd1review/en/), [teardown of LG-1](https://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2018/06/teardown-of-LG-1-led-light-guide-for-olympus-tough-tg.html)

Answer (score 5):

Some comparisons:
FD-1 is compatible with only TG-4 (Firmware update is required) and the TG-5. The shooting distance is 2 - 30 cm and is usable underwater.

LG-1 is compatible TG-5, TG-4, TG-3, TG-2, TG-1. The shooting distance  is 1 - 10 cm and is *not* usable underwater.

A interesting Olympus website is:
http://cameras.olympus.com/tg4fd1review/en/
This goes into detail mostly about the FD-1, but there is a bit about the FD-1 vs. FG-1.

Comment: Welcome to Photo.SE. Nice answer!